# Angularjs: directive that call function and send attributes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this HTML line:

```
<input type="text" id="textComment" ng-model="userComment" data-user="<?php echo $user->uid; ?>" data-nid="<?php echo $message->field_message_entity_reference['und'][0]['target_id']; ?>" class="form-control"  placeholder="Write something, upload a photo and push QUEBUTTON" comment-submit-on-return data-function="sendComment(attrs)">
```

And this directive :

```
angular.module('queApp').directive('commentSubmitOnReturn',[function() {
        return {
            link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log("commentSubmitOnReturn ");
                console.log(attrs);
                element.bind("keypress", function(event) {
                    if (event.which == 13) {
                        scope.$apply(attrs.function);
                        return;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }]);
})();
```

This directive works (the attrs.function is called), but what I need it is to pass "attrs" values to the function that is called via $scope.apply.

I have tried with scope.$apply(attrs.function)(attrs) but without success.

Where is my error ?

Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Ehhh ??? I have asked what I need "what I need it is to pass "attrs" values to the function that is called via $scope.apply." I have write what I use (html). I have write the code that does not work. If I can not ask where is my error, what could I ask for? Why works ? Sorry but I have not understand your reply.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to substitute in html:

```
data-function="sendComment(attrs)"
```

with

```
data-function="scope.sendComment(attrs)">
```

And in the directive:

```
scope.$apply(attrs.function);
```

with

```
scope.$apply(function() { eval(attrs.function)(attrs); });
```

Hope this can help other peoples.